# Not able to remove parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and there I am getting a value from input tag and then insert input value in a div and appending on screen with children element.

And What I want that when user click on children element then parent div would be removed and for this I'm using a function. That is working when I am using by default a section but when I append a section and then click on that's children where a function call like when user click on it's children parent section would be removed but my functionality not working.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var menuFieldName = $('#text').val();
  $('.div').append('<div class="a">' + menuFieldName + '<span>X</span></div>');
  $('#text').val('');
});

$('.div .a span').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="a">Test <span>X</span></div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="text">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jafaruddeen/rag71ma0/

Answer (score 2):

You are appending elements dynamically but you are not attaching any event handler to the newly added elements. To solve this you can use event delegation, you can attach events to `.div` like `$('.div').on('click', '.a span', function() {`

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var menuFieldName = $('#text').val();
  $('.div').append('<div class="a">' + menuFieldName + '<span>X</span></div>');
  $('#text').val('');
});

$('.div').on('click', '.a span', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div">
  <div class="a">Test <span>X</span></div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="text">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
```

Comment: thank you for solution :) actually I'm learner of jquery/javascript please help me how can I use e.target in my code

Comment: @Xufox `this` works here perfectly fine, it references the span element with X.

Comment: @JafaruddeenAnsari why do you wanna use e.target here?

Comment: "this" is working fine but I just I wanted to ask as @Xufox suggested me to replace this by "e.target" and provide "e" as a parameter that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @JafaruddeenAnsari i dont think you need to replace `this` with e.target, it is working correctly as in the snippet.

Comment: @JafaruddeenAnsari consider accepting the answer, if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't remove it is because when you register the event, the element on which you try to register it doesn't exist yet.

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('body').on('click', '#my-element', function(){...});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy :) for knowledgeable information

Answer (score 0):

you have to call click function after append.. or call click function globally(body element) and match the span..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').on('click',function(){
            var menuFieldName = $('#text').val();
            $('.div').append('<div class="a">'+menuFieldName+'<span class="close">X</span></div>');
            $('.div .a span').on('click', a);
            $('#text').val('');
        });

            $('.div .a span').on('click', a);    
    function a() {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

check your js fiddle. fixed it -> https://jsfiddle.net/jafaruddeen/rag71ma0/

Comment: and next option will be event delegation as per Radioreve suggession